# Site Isolation in Multisite Sitecore Instance Specifically as it Applies to Sitecore

Tags: git, sitecore

I understand similar questions have been asked with regards to site isolation in a multisite Sitecore instance, especially where [Tim's multi-site solution](https://github.com/jerrong/Sitecore-Multisite-Manager) is mentioned, but I'm looking for further clarity before attempting to fully implement Tim's code.

We're currently working with a Sitecore instance which houses nearly ten sites at this time.  We have a singular Visual Studio solution which, in one way or another, feeds all sites into a single code base, such that all DLLs are communal, and any other files can be as well.  We've more or less begun to handle this by breaking up all the sites into their own projects, with each of their project structures mirroring the singular, final structure.  This merely allows for less "churn" when modifying items like the .csproj files, reducing conflicts with other developers who are working in parallel.  Though this is definitely a nice item to have, its more of a convenience than what we're truly after.

For a little bit more background, we have five total Sitecore instances in one "stream", which are the local developer's instance, the development instance, the staging instance, and then two production instances.  We're managing changes with Git.

At this time we're unable to make a compiled change, say a change to any code-behind as it applies to one item in one site (which does not affect the other sites functionally), and deploy that compiled change without other sites having to rely on that DLL.  The main way that this becomes a problem is that we can't guarantee that all sites will still run when any code is pushed out; any change to one single site could break all sites at once.   There have been instances where I have made code changes that were erroneously deployed to development that broke all sites, so this is a fully-realized issue. We also don't want to have to test every site every time there is a code change, when we could have upwards of thirty sites in Sitecore in the near future.

Perhaps Tim's multi-site solution does this, but is there any way to truly isolate sites so that they don't all rely on the same DLLs?  Could we then have separate Visual Studio solutions for each website (which I feel would be ideal)?  I've seen other answers that have mentioned Tim's solution as "isolating", but that has been too ambiguous for me.  To what extent does Tim's solution "isolate" sites?  Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

A single Sitecore application instance is essentially a virtual hosting environment for one or more front end sites. Each site is made up of layouts and UI components that may be shared but they don't have to. That said, you can duplicate your components across separate projects or solutions for each site and this will solve that problem. However it opens another problem of duplicate code on all sites. Fix one issue and you need to many times. Also when you deploy a DLL it will recycle the app pool so all sites will restart since it's the same application instance. The best guidance I can give is to be organized and have some coding governance. Perhaps a set of common utilities used by all sites which may be prone to breaking multiple sites should be very carefully changed. While site specific components are more on the fringe and have less impact. Also, don't couple your UI components to too many layers of inheritance and code in common utilities. Although it might make sense logically, it creates a lot of coupling that may contribute to your problem. Just my 2 cents based on experience with the same challenges.

In our case we have a core utility library shared by all sites, a core web project for shared UI components, then separate site-specific web projects for components just in those sites. We also avoid global config changes where possible and "over patching" of features like events and pipelines. Instead try to keep your code to scope to a specific site.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to **truly isolate** Sitecore sites and deployment you can opt for a model where each site has it own solution, IIS Website (and application pool), deployment pipeline and all shared functionality / configuration are done through NuGet packages. In this model you have a single CM server where web is shared by all sites.

Furthermore you can isolate publishing with a custom Event Provider on each site that only raises events relevant for items for a given site so that cache is not cleared on all sites on every publish.

This way of isolation is currently running in production with 70+ sites per server and ~ 80 developers spread across ~10 teams.

Comment: This is interesting and I agree, but the BIG caveat here is licensing since each instance is a license used

Comment: Yes this is unfortunately true with the current Sitecore licensing model. But for customers with an suitable license its a valid option.